# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alternative that allows selection of multiple people

Tags: iphone, uikit

I'd like to prompt the user to select 1 or more people from their address book, but `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` doesn't allow that (which is ironic, since it's *people* picker, not a *person* picker).

Before I go create my own, does anyone know of an alternative (open source) implementation of such a controller?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the People Picker delegate has the following:

`peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:`

Which, if you return NO, you can perform logic (queue up info, perform an animation, etc) and then continue displaying the picker until all people are picked from the picker.... say that 12 times fast.

Comment: Yeah, but I'd like the users to be at least able to see the people they picked (e.g. by a checkmark) and un-pick them if they made an accident. I could hack that into ABPeoPicNavCon, but it'd smells of private API use to me.

Comment: Did u find a solution? If yes, please share.

Answer (score -1):

Check this thread out:

[deselectRowAtIndexPath on an ABPeoplePickerNavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314653/deselectrowatindexpath-on-an-abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller)

Not perfect, but a good start. Subclass ABPeoplePickerNavigationController and insert the code into:

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController*)peoplePicker 
    shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person

Comment: The documentation for ABPeoplePickerNavigationController has this to say about subclassing: "The ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class does not support subclassing."